# Join two table, count column rows on three where statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `lot_bill_of_operations` with lines and table `lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref` which has serial number and timestamp columns. The tables are related by primary key `bol_id`.

I am trying to count how many serial numbers are passed on three shifts group by line, but I have same result for each subquery.

Here is the query:

```
select lot_bill_of_operations.wc_line_code,

(select  count(part_sn) from lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref
  where lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref.time_stamp between '07-MAY-17 06:00:00'
    and '07-MAY-17 14:00:00'
  group by lot_bill_of_operations.wc_line_code)firstshift,

(select  count(part_sn) from lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref
  where lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref.time_stamp between '07-MAY-17 14:00:00'
    and '07-MAY-17 22:00:00'
  group by lot_bill_of_operations.wc_line_code)secondshift,

(select  count(part_sn) from lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref
  where lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref.time_stamp between '07-MAY-17 22:00:00'
    and '08-MAY-17 06:00:00'
  group by lot_bill_of_operations.wc_line_code)thirdshift

FROM lot_bill_of_operations inner JOIN lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref
    ON lot_bill_of_operations.bol_id = lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref.bol_id
group by lot_bill_of_operations.wc_line_code
```

And here is the results that gets:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give some sample data and your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want conditional counts, which you can get with a case expression:

```
select lbo.wc_line_code,
  count(case when lblsx.time_stamp between timestamp '2017-05-07 06:00:00'
    and timestamp '2017-05-07 14:00:00' then lblsx.part_sn end) as firstshift,
  count(case when lblsx.time_stamp between timestamp '2017-05-07 14:00:00'
    and timestamp '2017-05-07 22:00:00' then lblsx.part_sn end) as secondshift,
  count(case when lblsx.time_stamp between timestamp '2017-05-07 22:00:00'
    and timestamp '2017-05-08 06:00:00' then lblsx.part_sn end) as thirdshift
from lot_bill_of_operations lbo
inner join lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref lblsx
on lbo.bol_id = lblsx.bol_id
group by lbo.wc_line_code;
```

I've switched to timestamp literals, as you are relying on your NLS settings to implicitly convert strings to timestamps. (Or possibly dates, it isn't clear from what you've shown).

However, using `between` means the periods overlap slightly, so you might really want:

```
select lbo.wc_line_code,
  count(case when lblsx.time_stamp >= timestamp '2017-05-07 06:00:00'
    and lblsx.time_stamp < timestamp '2017-05-07 14:00:00' then lblsx.part_sn end) as firstshift,
  count(case when lblsx.time_stamp >= timestamp '2017-05-07 14:00:00'
    and lblsx.time_stamp < timestamp '2017-05-07 22:00:00' then lblsx.part_sn end) as secondshift,
  count(case when lblsx.time_stamp >= timestamp '2017-05-07 22:00:00'
    and lblsx.time_stamp < timestamp '2017-05-08 06:00:00' then lblsx.part_sn end) as thirdshift
from lot_bill_of_operations lbo
inner join lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref lblsx
on lbo.bol_id = lblsx.bol_id
group by lbo.wc_line_code;
```

You might also want to include the `time_stamp` range as an overall filter to reduce the amount of data inspected:

```
...
where lblsx.time_stamp >= timestamp '2017-05-07 06:00:00'
and lblsx.time_stamp < timestamp '2017-05-08 06:00:00'
group by lbo.wc_line_code;
```

If you're basing this on the current day you can use date arithmetic instead of fixed values.

Comment: Maybe not the right forum to ask this, but does the string format after `timestamp` will always be `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss` or will it depend on NLS settings.

Comment: @Utsav - [datetime ANSI literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) are fixed unambiguous formats, though time zone info is optional. They don't rely on NLS at all - which is why I prefer them for static values (rather than variables). The only slightly annoying thing about them is that you can't have an ANSI date literal with a time component, you have to use a timestamp literal (but can then cast that back to a date).

Comment: Thanks. Nice article also. I spent way too much time casting string via `to_date`, which I could have avoided. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample data, it is difficult to understand what you want, but based on your query, I believe you need something like below.

- Also avoid comparing string for dates. Use a date conversion function
  like `to_date`/`to_timestamp` while comparing dates for accurate and
  non ambiguous results.
- Use `between` while giving a range.
- Use
  alias for table names for better readability.

  ```
  select o.wc_line_code
      ,count(case when 
              x.time_stamp between to_date('07-MAY-17 06:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') 
                              and  to_date('07-MAY-17 14:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
              then 1) as firstshift
  -- , similary for other shifts

  FROM lot_bill_of_operations o 
      inner JOIN 
       lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref x
      ON o.bol_id = x.bol_id
  group by o.wc_line_code;
  ```

Comment: My only quibble with this is continuing to use `between`, which I realise is in the question; but a row with the time at exactly 14:00:00 will be counted in both first and second shifts. That *could* be what the OP wants but looks more like an accident.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't realize it at all before reading your answer. I see you have explained it clearly so OP would understand the difference between the two, as I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select lot_bill_of_operations.wc_line_code
, sum (case when time_stamp between '07-MAY-17 06:00:00' and '07-MAY-17 14:00:00'
 then 1 else 0 end ) firstshift
, sum (case when time_stamp between '07-MAY-17 14:00:00' and '07-MAY-17 22:00:00'
 then 1 else 0 end ) secondshift
, sum (case when time_stamp between '07-MAY-17 22:00:00' and '08-MAY-17 06:00:00'
 then 1 else 0 end ) thirdshift
FROM lot_bill_of_operations inner JOIN lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref
    ON lot_bill_of_operations.bol_id = lot_bill_of_lots_serial_xref.bol_id
group by lot_bill_of_operations.wc_line_code
;
```